# Uncovered set versus top cycle set (voting theory)

Tags: voting

I am struggling to see when, given a policy set  $X = {x_{1}, … , x_{m}} $ , with $m > 1$, its uncovered set and top cycle set may not coincide (i.e. when the top cycle set has policies that are not in the uncovered set).

The **uncovered set** is defined as follows. Policy $x$ covers $y$ if (1) it is majority-preferred to $y$, and (2) all policies that are majority-preferred to $x$ are likewise preferred to $y$. If there is no $x$ that satisfies criteria (1) and (2), then we say that $y$ is uncovered.

Next to this, the **top cycle set** is defined by partitioning the policy set into k disjoint subsets, $${L_{1}, … , L_{k}}, \text{where} \; 1 \leq k \leq m $$ by iteratively applying the idea of the top cycle set, where
$$(L_{1} = {x ∈ X | \; ∄ \; y ∈ X / L_{1} \; s.t. \; y \succ x})$$

We call these subsets of $X$ levels to suggest a mental picture: one can see the electoral environment as a series of levels or plateaus (if $k > 1$). Each plateau electorally dominates those below it: each policy at a given level is majority-preferred to all policies at lower levels. Further, every policy at a level covers all policies at lower elevations. This implies that $X$’s uncovered set is a subset of $L_{1}$, the uncovered set of $X / L_{1}$ is a subset of $L_{2}$, and so forth.

Defined constructively in this setting, a policy is in the top cycle set ($L_{1}$)  if and only if it is reachable from every other policy by a chain of straight majority preference.

Specifically, given the above definition I cannot understand why the above definition of the top cycle set *implies that $X$’s uncovered set is a subset of $L_{1}$*.

If anyone could think of an example or some other explanation/input for this I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example comes from [Miller (1980)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2110925) (the paper that introduced the uncovered set definition).

Suppose that the majority's preference is defined by:

\begin{aligned}
x \succ y \\
x \succ z \\
y \succ v \\
y \succ z \\
v \succ x \\
z \succ v
\end{aligned}

In this example, we have the top cycle set $L_1 = \{x, y, z, v \}$ (you can check this).

But notice that $y$ is preferred to $z$ and all policies that are preferred to $y$ (namely $x$), are preferred to $z$. So, $y$ covers $z$ and the uncovered set $U$ is such that $U = \{x, y, v\}$ and $U \subset L_1$.

Among other stuff that Miller proves in his paper, we have the following three:

1. if there is a Condorcet winner, $L_1 = U$;
2. if $L_1$ has three elements, then $L_1 = U$;
3. $U \subseteq L_1$.